# Reading Text File From Webpage by Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, html

```
import re
import urllib
hand=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt")
qq=hand.read().decode('utf-8') 
numlist=[]
for line in qq:
    line.rstrip()
    stuff=re.findall("^X-DSPAM-Confidence: ([0-9.]+)",line)
    if len(stuff)!=1:
        continue
    num=float(stuff[0])
    numlist.append(num)
print('Maximum:',max(numlist))
```

The variable `qq` contains all the strings from the text file. However, the `for` loop doesn't work and `numlist` is still empty.

When I download the text file as a local file then read it, everything is ok.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please clarify.

Comment: In the textfile, there is a floating number for every line which starts with the string "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" . e.g. X-DSPAM-Confidence: 60.69. I am going to pick the largest one from those numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex on qq using the multiline flag `re.M`, you are iterating over a string so going *character by character*, not *line by line* so you are calling findall on single characters:

```
In [18]: re.findall("^X-DSPAM-Confidence: ([0-9.]+)",qq, re.M)
Out [18]: ['0.8475', '0.6178', '0.6961', '0.7565', '0.7626', '0.7556', '0.7002', '0.7615', '0.7601', '0.7605', '0.6959', '0.7606', '0.7559', '0.7605', '0.6932', '0.7558', '0.6526', '0.6948', '0.6528', '0.7002', '0.7554', '0.6956', '0.6959', '0.7556', '0.9846', '0.8509', '0.9907']
```

What you are doing is equivalnet to:

```
In [13]: s = "foo\nbar"

In [14]: for c in s:
   ....:    stuff=re.findall("^X-DSPAM-Confidence: ([0-9.]+)",c)
            print(c)
   ....:     
f
o
o


b
a
r
```

If you want floats, you can cast with `map`:

```
list(map(float,re.findall("^X-DSPAM-Confidence: ([0-9.]+)",qq, re.M)))
```

But if you just want the max, you can pass a key to `max`:

```
In [22]: max(re.findall("^X-DSPAM-Confidence: ([0-9.]+)",qq, re.M),key=float)
Out[22]: '0.9907'
```

So all you need is three lines:

```
In [28]: hand=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt")

In [29]: qq = hand.read().decode('utf-8')

In [30]: max(re.findall("^X-DSPAM-Confidence: ([0-9.]+)",qq, re.M),key=float)
Out[30]: '0.9907'
```

If you wanted to go line by line, iterate directly over `hand` :

```
import re
import urllib

hand = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt")
numlist = []
# iterate over each line like a file object
for line in hand:
    stuff = re.search("^X-DSPAM-Confidence: ([0-9.]+)", line.decode("utf-8"))
    if stuff:
        numlist.append(float(stuff.group(1)))
print('Maximum:', max(numlist))
```